# CRFSuite binding for python: Build the binding failed

Tags: python, python-crfsuite

Has anybody faced the following error while trying the "Build the binding" step (`$ python setup.py build_ext`) in CRFSuite and have any idea how to fix it?

```
running build_ext
building '_crfsuite' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\include" "-IC:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Python33\include" /Tpcrfsuite.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.3\Release\crfsuite.obj
crfsuite.cpp
crfsuite.cpp(1) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```